# Sounds make Andengine Scene junky

Tags: android, andengine, android-studio

I have a `GameScene` which has a character (animated sprite), `AutoParallaxBackground` background with quite large textures and no more than 3 other items attached to the scene at a time, previous 3 items are `dispose()`-ed accordingly, background music and item sounds. Background music is instantiated with `MusicFactory`, Sounds are played on `SoundPool`. In between switching these scene we are loading resources asynchronously, reading the streams and instantiation is done in `AsyncTask` and the loading textures to the hardware is done on `UpdateThread`/`GLThread`. If I turn off the background music, this starts to happen totally random.

I'm experiencing scene junking on at first flow: `MenuScene` -> 1st Stage (`GameScene`). After a while lag does not happen, rather than occasionally or random. Junk is happening when aforementioned 3 items are attached on the Scene and a sound is played along, note that background music is playing at the same time.

Detaching previous 3 items is "optimized" to reduce GC calling almost perfectly. When the lag occurs `GC_EXPLICIT` is showed in the logcat.

What I have tried:

- Playing the sounds and music on different thread, `IntentService`, dedicated Service.
- Reduced calls to `mScene.detachChild(child)` and other scene methods to avoid iterations over children of the scene.
- Detaching `IEntity`s with matcher to avoid iteration.
- Inspected sound files' integrity with ffmpeg for possible errors

Could `.dispose()`, unloading the textures from hardware or `detachChild()` causing this junk?

Could be marked object for GC from the async tasks be causing this?

What else could be contributing to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After we have optimized the attaching and got rid of unnecessary look ups for scene children we've gained more fps as we advanced.

Occasional hiccups that were caused by `GC_EXPLICIT` were happening because `Font` in `update()` was explicitly calling `System.gc()`. Removing this line we were back on track below the green line, yeah! 60fps.

However, the author of AndEngine might had reasons for this explicit call. Since the stages are short we granted our app call this `gc()` when the `GameScene` is paused,  quit or stage complete, anywhere where there is no excessive animation.

**Edit**:

Another thing that could contribute to the fps drop is the `SoundPool`. Every time `SoundPool` is done playing with sounds in the pool, it resets its state to idle perhaps, when the next sound is played it takes a 8ms+ to reload its state to different state than idle. To avoid this you need to play looping sound with 0 left and right volume.